# Specifying a function

Tags: functions, notation

I am currently watching (on YouTube) Fredric Schuller's lectures given in 2015 at The WE-Heraeus International Winter School on Gravity and Light and have a question about how Dr. Schuller talks about maps.

He starts by stating the following:

Let $M, N $ be sets and a map $f: M \to N$ where $m \in M$ such that $f: m \mapsto f(m) $.

He then goes on to elaborate and says "if $M, N \subset \mathbb{R}$ then we can give a **definite prescription** $f(m)=m^2$." What does he mean by a *definite prescription*? I have provided the link at the bottem of this post to the lecture if anyone would like to take a listen.

[Lecture 1: Topology (International Winter School on Gravity and Light 2015)](https://youtu.be/7G4SqIboeig?t=2319)

Comment: I find it strange that a map would be defined after a topological space. Anyway, he just means that in this case, $f(m)=m^2$ could be stated as the explicit definition of what $f$ does to $m$.

Comment: You should really watch his lectures, he is one of my biggest role models! Always clear and precise. Thank you very much as well, that makes more sense than what I was thinking.